# Importing to pgsql from gpkg/shp with ogr2ogr

Tags: postgis, gdal, ogr2ogr, import, geopackage

I am trying to import features from a geopackage (or a shapefile) in an existing table of a distant PostgreSQL database. I use ogr2ogr which I run from OSGeo4W Shell.

The code used with the geopackage is:

```
ogr2ogr -update -append -progress -f PostgreSQL -nln schema.my_table PG:"dbname=my_database host=my_server user=me password=my_password port=5433" D:\temp\SIG\my_geopackage.gpkg
```

The code used with the shapefile (an export from the gpkg) is:

```
ogr2ogr -update -append -progress -f PostgreSQL -sql "SELECT [variables as var] from my_shapefile" -nln schema.my_table PG:"dbname=my_database host=my_server user=me password=my_password port=5433" D:\temp\SIG\my_shapefile.shp
```

(in this case I must call a select to rename the variables as their name is truncated by the conversion in shp)

In both case, I get a "done" message and I can find the data is my_table BUT their are not spatial anymore... I mean I can't see the polygons corresponding to each line.

What do I do wrong?

Comment: Do you have the postgis extension installed for your postgres database?

Comment: Yes, the extension is installed. I can see all the previous polygones from QGIS but not the new ones... Maybe it can be usefull to say that the table contains both polygones, polylines and points... In this case I am only importing polygones.

Comment: have you tried putting your source path in quotes? "D:\temp\SIG\my_geopackage.gpkg"

Comment: I've just tried: it gives the same results...

Comment: Hmm alright, could you be more specific about what you mean by 'the polygons corresponding to each line? And how do you know they're not spatial anymore?

Comment: In the table, each line is supposed to correspond to a polygon (or polyline or point). When I access the table from QGIS, I can see all the polygons except those corresponding to the newly imported (from the shapefile or the gpkg) lines....

Comment: Do these newly imported records have a geometry column?

Comment: Yes, but it is empty !

Comment: So to get this straight: You have table in your postgis db with geometries. To this you want to add/append new rows from a geopackage or shapefile via a gdal script? But the data you're adding this way has no geometry?

Comment: Yes! That's it ! Maybe there is a way to "generate" the geometry column in qgis before the import?

Comment: Well if qgis is displaying the 'original' polygons from the exact same table, that should not be the issue. There are two things I can think of right now: 
1. The data in your gpkg has no geometry or
2. The geometry in your gpkg does not contain polygons but some other kind geometry. 
So are you sure the geopackage you are importing has polygons?

Comment: OK! For some reason the gpkg was corrupted. Just in case some people are stuck with the same issue, here is the workaround:
- under QGIS, export your postgis table as a gpkg with a polygon geometry and forcing the geometry type as multi. Don't forget to adapt the geometry column name to the one used in your postgis table.
- suppress all lines (polygons) from this new gpkg 
- copy/past the polygones from the corrupted gpkg to the new one
- save the changes and run the import command line

Thank you very much for your help Konan !